# Underfull \hbox (badness 1158) due to single word name

Tags: bibliographies, author

I wrote the following reference in my .bib file through Mendeley:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Reichstein et~al.(2019)Reichstein, Camps-Valls, Stevens, Jung,
  Denzler, Carvalhais, and Prabhat]{Reichstein2019}
Markus Reichstein, Gustau Camps-Valls, Bjorn Stevens, Martin Jung, Joachim
  Denzler, Nuno Carvalhais, and Prabhat.
\newblock {Deep learning and process understanding for data-driven Earth system
  science}.
\newblock \emph{Nature}, 566:\penalty0 195--204, 2019.
\newblock ISSN 0028-0836.
\newblock \doi{10.1038/s41586-019-0912-1}.
\newblock URL \url{www.nature.com/nature}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Because of this reference, LaTeX gave me a warning:

underful \hbox (badness 1158)

I believe the cause of this error is the name of the last author. He has a single word name. If I put some word as his last name, latex gave me no error.

How can I solve this error without modifying his name for his honor?

Comment: It would be better you show us a short compilable tex code building your bibliography and add the complete used bib entry from your menderly file to your question.  Your shown `*.bbl` file is compiled, we have to guess what you did in the tex code I mentioned before ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I should have well learned how to ask questions here before I did.

Comment: Well, it is not to late to add the mentioned informations :-) You can edit your question!

Answer (score 1):

The bib-label cannot spann over multiple lines. I would remove all the names from the bib-label and put them afterwards:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Reichstein2019}


\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Reichstein et~al.(2019)]{Reichstein2019}
Markus Reichstein, Gustau Camps-Valls, Bjorn Stevens, Martin Jung, Joachim
  Denzler, Nuno Carvalhais, and Prabhat.
\newblock {Deep learning and process understanding for data-driven Earth system
  science}.
\newblock \emph{Nature}, 566:\penalty0 195--204, 2019.
\newblock ISSN 0028-0836.
\newblock \doi{10.1038/s41586-019-0912-1}.
\newblock URL \url{www.nature.com/nature}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried your code on my Texstudio, but still got an error. The error is 'line 16 underfull \hbox (badness5519) in paragraph'.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error: just warning you that tex stretched the inter-word spaces a bit to much on that line. You could simply ignore it. 1158 is not that bad: Normally latex doesn't warn if badness is under 1000, so you could set

```
\hbadness=1200
```

before your bibliography  and it won't warn about this either.

Comment: while this is true in general, your particular case of an `et al` shortened list followed by the full name list looks very strange, is that really the output you want? I may delete this answer as it just answers the tex issue rather than the content (as you did not provide a usable example)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the badness number and it worked. Honestly, I did not care the strange 'et al' which were generated by Mendeley automatically.